# How to reactivate sounds from youtube after using SoundMixer.stopAll()?

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, youtube, flash-cs5, frame

I have an youtube video playing in a specific frame. After researching a lot and not being able to properly destroy the player when exiting the frame, I decided to put a SoundMixer.stopAll() in all frames that can be used to get out from the youtube one. That makes things right in most of cases, because to access the video again I must click a button that reloads the player and everything gets back to the start. But I have some thumbs on the right side of the page that when clicked open a large image, occupying most of the page and not showing the video button, but they have a close button themselves. When I click the close button that movieclip becomes invisible and the one with the youtube video becomes visible again (what's great in all other cases). The point is: the player kept playing in the background and when I close the image you can see it playing again, but without sound. The only way to make the sound audible again is clicking on the seek bar (because it isn't a flash component itself, differently of the play/pause button) or going to another frame (that not one from the thumbs/images) and coming back. How could I make the sound play again automatically when entering the frame? Help to destroy the player when exiting the frame is also welcome.